# How to calculate vortex movement in fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-equations, vortex

I'm going mad...I just want to understand:

Given there are three vortices of type "[Rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_vortex)" in an incompressible 2D-fluid, each having radius R and a given vorticity  $\Omega$ inside r<R. Outside R vorticity is zero, but velocity is azimuthal and proportional to $\Omega/r$.

In particular, we have a vortex in the middle (with arbitrary vorticity) between two vortices with same vorticity on the left and right as follows (all radii R are 1):

[image]

With this a an initial condition, how are the three vortices developing in time? Are they moving?
The question in particular is: is vortex A moving?

How can such situation be calculated?

Naively thinking, I would calculate the velocity field (u, v) due to the three vortices, just by adding their contributions. Then for each field point I could calculate the new position according to

$$\dot{x} = u, \\ \dot{y} = v$$

but at the same time the vorticity

$$\zeta = \partial v/\partial x - \partial u/\partial y$$

of each point must be conserved due to vorticity equation: $d \zeta /dt = 0$ (we have no divergence and no tilting terms). For a point inside the original circle  A we have a fixed initial value $\zeta =\Omega_0$. Wherever this point moves around due to advection, it's vorticity must stay the same:

$$\partial \zeta /\partial t + (\vec v \cdot \vec \nabla) \zeta = 0$$

How can his set of partial differential equation be solved numerically? I cannot figure out how it can be separated in a set of finite difference equations to be solved numerically when time is incremented by a small step forward.

I did only the very fist timestep to get new positions using a naïve excel calculation: I just added the velocity field from the initially circular vortices on the left and right to get $\vec x' = \vec x + \vec v dt$ . Of course, because of symmetry, the center of A does not move, but the points of the original circle around A seems to get deformed: is is still a circle?

[image]

So, is it true that this deformation takes place or must the three vortices stay circular all the time by some physical argument?

**This question is due to a kind of exercise, where even a fourth vortex is placed at point D and the question is, in which direction vortex A will move**:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The expected answer must be simple since we have no experience with numerical solution of PDEs and such a procedure would be out of scope.

To answer the question: If I just look at point A, I'm inclined to say that it would move to the right or left since there is a net velocity due to the vortex at D. But what does “move” mean when the vortex becomes also deformed? If the vortex deforms in the more simpler configuration, this must also be the case here. Furthermore, vortices A and D overlap in terms of their active areas where the vorticity is not zero.

I have absolutely no plan how to proceed...What is the right approach to tackle such kind of problems?

Could it be that the exercise needs to be oversimplified by ignoring all these complications and only considering point A? Given the true complexity, that would be rather disappointing for me...

Comment: Right now I'm not at home, but I'm interested in this question (and I should be able to help you). I'm saving this question to provide you an answer later or next days

Comment: By the way, did you realize that the velocity field you're providing is not continuous? Or should one interpret the (initial state of the) velocity field as the superposition of the fields produced by those three Rankine vortices?

Comment: Yes, I would have superimposed the three vortices to get the initial velocity field. And then there is a fourth vortex that sits at the top. The question was how vortex 1 moves. I don't normally want to get my tasks solved, but I don't see a way to go about it here...I cannot imagine, that the vortices all stay circular, at least not, when there is a strong core overlap between A and D.

Comment: What is a vortex? You have to define it, before you start evaluating its evolution. And there is no unambiguous definition of "vortex"

Comment: The exercise doesn't not specify this. Just assumes there are three vortices (left, right, upper) with given strengths and one vortex  (strength unspecified) located in the origin. Question is, in which direction it moves by virtue of the others. That's all.

Comment: If you can assume the vortices have "small" cores, so that you can approximate them as point vortices with regular(ized) core, the answer is easy. Just use mutual induction between these vortices

Comment: yes, but the geometry was given as in the image: core distance = 2*core radius. I think the exercise was not well thought out by the professor. Anyway, I would be interested how such problem could be solved numerically...

Comment: My personal experience tells me that there are more bad teachers of fluid dynamics than one can think, who design exercises and examples that they can explain and are much more confusing than clarifying